# Need to ignore textual quotes in a JavaScript table sorting function

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code I have:

```
        function makeSortFunction(type, direction, index) {
            var a = "a[" + index + "]",
                b = "b[" + index + "]";
            if (type == 'text' && direction == 'asc') {
                return "(" + a + " == " + b + " ? 0 : (" + a + " === null ? Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY : (" + b + " === null ? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : (" + a + " < " + b + ") ? -1 : 1 )));";
            } else if (type == 'text' && direction == 'desc') {
                return "(" + a + " == " + b + " ? 0 : (" + a + " === null ? Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY : (" + b + " === null ? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : (" + b + " < " + a + ") ? -1 : 1 )));";
            } else if (type == 'numeric' && direction == 'asc') {
                return "(" + a + " === null && " + b + " === null) ? 0 :(" + a + " === null ? Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY : (" + b + " === null ? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : " + a + " - " + b + "));";
            } else if (type == 'numeric' && direction == 'desc') {
                return "(" + a + " === null && " + b + " === null) ? 0 :(" + a + " === null ? Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY : (" + b + " === null ? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : " + b + " - " + a + "));";
            }
        };

        function makeSortText(i) {
            return "((a[" + i + "] < b[" + i + "]) ? -1 : ((a[" + i + "] > b[" + i + "]) ? 1 : 0));";
        };

        function makeSortTextDesc(i) {
            return "((b[" + i + "] < a[" + i + "]) ? -1 : ((b[" + i + "] > a[" + i + "]) ? 1 : 0));";
        };

        function makeSortNumeric(i) {
            return "a[" + i + "]-b[" + i + "];";
        };

        function makeSortNumericDesc(i) {
            return "b[" + i + "]-a[" + i + "];";
        };

        function sortText(a, b) {
            if (table.config.sortLocaleCompare) return a.localeCompare(b);
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        };

        function sortTextDesc(a, b) {
            if (table.config.sortLocaleCompare) return b.localeCompare(a);
            return ((b < a) ? -1 : ((b > a) ? 1 : 0));
        };

        function sortNumeric(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        };

        function sortNumericDesc(a, b) {
            return b - a;
        };

        function getCachedSortType(parsers, i) {
            return parsers[i].type;
        }; /* public methods */
```

This works extremely well for me EXCEPT that anything with a quote (all my article titles are using single quotes), or in one instance a dollar symbol, end up at the top of an ascending sort. I would really like a way to get those things in alphanumeric order with the rest of the list.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are these JavaScript functions being used?

Comment: You can view my use of it on this page: http://www.tractorsupply.com/out-here_Out-Here-Magazine-Archives_tsc-out-here-magazine-article-index.html

Comment: I don't see it... Can you post the code that calls one or more of the above functions?

Comment: Don't return strings, which will have to be eval'ed. Return closures.

Comment: for MatthiasDailey -- The jquery referenced is over 1000 lines of code. This is at the top:

/*
 * 
 * TableSorter 2.0 - Client-side table sorting with ease!
 * Version 2.0.5b
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Christian Bach
 * Examples and docs at: http://tablesorter.com
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * 
 */

for Barmar -- forgive my ignorance, but where JS is concerned, I haven't used what I've learned enough to remember the distinction, but I'll look it up.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the entire text contents of each cell are used for sorting by the `tableSorter` jQuery plugin. You can override this by means of the `config.textExtraction` filter, which would be done in the line of your code where you call the `tableSorter` plugin.

You did not include that portion of your code, so in general, it would look like this, including the necessary call for the customized text extraction function:

```
$("#myTable").tableSorter( {textExtraction: myTextExtraction} );
```

You would then write a text extraction function that would trim leading/trailing characters of whitespace AND quotation marks.

```
function myTextExtraction(s) {
  return s.replace(/^[\s'"]+|[\s'"]+$/g, '');
}
```

I don't see any "smart" (curly) quotes used on your website, but if you did, then you would need to add within the character class the appropriate Unicode code point for each of those types of quotation marks.

#### After taking a look at your site...

You just need to add the custom function `myTextExtraction` above to your code, and then add the additional `textExtraction` parameter. After checking over your site's existing JavaScript code, something like this might work for you:

```
function myTextExtraction(s) {
  return s.replace(/^[\s'"]+|[\s'"]+$/g, '');
}

$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: myTextExtraction, widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']
  }).tablesorterPager({
    textExtraction: myTextExtraction, container: $("#pager");
  });
});
```

That code would be in place the current code on your site which is this: `$(function() {        $("table")          .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});    });`

Comment: Hm. Well, I put the first three lines in the .js file (does it matter where in the file?) and did the substitution of the $function as you recommended. I don't know if it's because our staging server is taking its time getting the js file published or if I put the code in wrong, but once the html file published to staging, the sort quit working entirely. I had to revert to the earlier version for the time being. I will put some more time into it later today, or tomorrow morning, and mess around till it works right. I really appreciate the help. It ought to work, so I'm not sure why it isn't.

Comment: @CaraColleenCoble the only changes that matter are the function `myTextExtraction` and the additional configuration parameter `textExtraction: myTextExtraction` within your call to the table sorter program. If your program stops working when you copy and paste, it could be that something else was changed by accident as well. So try making these changes individually.

Comment: Well, I've had a number of things going on this week, but still, it doesn't seem to matter how I apply the suggested code alterations above, the sort quits working. I did discover that there is already a function 'myTextExtraction' in the jquery, so I altered the new function name to 'myTextExtract'; however, I still wasn't able to make this work. I'm about ready to give up here and just live with the quotes sorting at the top of the table. No one ever responded to my comment about whether it matters WHERE in the jquery file that I put the added function. I'm assuming that could be an issue.